# How to do "Due in X days/time" for a todo app in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Say I have a todo app that has title and due_date fields. How do I say "Due in X days?" If a certain todo is due on Dec 29, it should say due in 2 days, X hours.

I suppose it was to do something with Time.now. I understand there's a

`<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now%>` is there an opposite to that?

Thanks

Comment: Really this is not that difficult in most languages. I dont know Rails but almost all languages support date manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here is how I solved it.

```
<% if post.date < Time.now -%>
   Due <%=h distance_of_time_in_words(post.date, Time.now) %> ago
<% else -%>
   Due in <%= distance_of_time_in_words(post.date, Time.now) %>
<% end -%>
```

I'll probably make the fonts different, say red for overdue.

Remember to change timezones if you are not living in coordinated universe time (UTC).

```
#First find your time zone
rake time:zones:local

#My output
* UTC -08:00 *
Pacific Time (US & Canada)
Tijuana

#Copy 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)' and replace line 46 in config/environment.rb
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

#Be sure to restart your server and you are set to go.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try from_now

```
3.days.from_now  #=> Thu, 31 Dec 2009 07:51:05 UTC +00:00
```

Can also work with hours

```
2.hours.from_now #=> Mon, 28 Dec 2009 11:54:07 UTC +00:00
```

and [the rails api page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M001243)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the implementation of `distance_of_time_in_words`: http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.5/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L62

Shouldn't be too hard to implement your own reversed version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is ported version

http://gaskell.org/rails-helper-distance_of_time_in_words-ported-to-c/